# Generating Haskell code from COQ: Logical or arity value used

Tags: haskell, coq, coq-extraction

I am currently trying to generate Haskell code from my program verification lemma, which looks like this:

```
Lemma the_thing_is_ok : forall (e:Something),  Matches e (calculate_value e).
```

Right after ending my Section, I do:

```
Extraction Language Haskell.
Recursive Extraction the_thing_is_ok
```

And it does not seem to be really happy about something, since it returns the following error:

```
__ = Prelude.error "Logical or arity value used"
```

I have another Lemma which does seem to export just fine but I could not figure out what the problem was exactly. Any clues on how to work around that error?

Comment: Is your Lemma in Prop, as usually is the case? I believe Coq discards all the Prop information during extraction. E.g. if you extract `{ n:nat | somePredicate n }` you will get a natural, but without the proof of the predicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coq erases values of type `Prop` during extraction—they're considered to have no computational meaning. If you have a computation which requires computing with a `Prop` then extraction will fail.

Comment: Just write your Props in Set. Everything ought to work there essentially the same—the only functional differences are exactly what makes Prop extraction break.